# PhpSpreadsheet me arroja texto encriptado en vez de iniciar la descarga

Tags: php, slim, phpspreadsheet

Estoy tratando de exportar un arreglo a un archivo de excel con esta librería pero al momento de hacerlo me arroja texto tipo `��ࡱ�;�` la cosa es que en dos de las tres variantes que tengo sí funciona, pero en esta última siempre me arroja este tipo de texto, ¿alguien sabe por qué?
Este es el arreglo con el que funciona perfecto y me tira la descarga en seguida:

```
Array
(
       [0] => Array
          (
            [id_asistente] => 1
            [nombre] => adfadsfas
            [inst_procedencia] => sadfsa
            [perfil_academico] => asdfasdf
            [estado] => asdfsaf
            [correo] => mail@gmail.com
            [cursos_inscritos] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_asistente] => 2
            [nombre] => asdfsafsaf
            [inst_procedencia] => asdfasfsa
            [perfil_academico] => asdfasdfsdf
            [estado] => sdfdsafadfs
            [correo] => mailll@gmail.com
            [cursos_inscritos] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_asistente] => 3
            [nombre] => asdfasfsfa
            [inst_procedencia] => asdffds
            [perfil_academico] => asdfasdfdsaf
            [estado] => asdfasdf
            [correo] => edu@gmail.com
            [cursos_inscritos] => 0
        )

    )
```

Y este es el arreglo que, no sé la razón, no quiere funcionar:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id_asistente] => 2
        [nombre] => asdasdasdad
        [inst_procedencia] => Asda
        [perfil_academico] => asdasd
        [estado] => asdass
        [correo] => mailll@gmail.com
        [asistencia] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id_asistente] => 4
        [nombre] => Aasdasdad
        [inst_procedencia] => asdsa
        [perfil_academico] => asdasd
        [estado] => asdasdas
        [correo] => asdasdsa@adasdsa.com
        [asistencia] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id_asistente] => 6
        [nombre] => asdasdas
        [inst_procedencia] => asdasd
        [perfil_academico] => asdasd
        [estado] => asddas
        [correo] => asdasdsa@gmail.com
        [asistencia] => 1
    )
)
```

Y esta es la función con la que hago la descarga:

```
function exportToExcel($data, $filename) {
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->fromArray($data, NULL, 'A1');

    $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xls');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $writer->save('php://output');
}
```

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: ¿Tienes alguna salida previa, HTML, `echo`, espacios o salto de línea? Seguramente por eso no se realiza la descarga y ves el contenido directamente en el navegador.

Comment: No, ya revisé todo el método y no tengo ningún `echo` que esté imprimiendo algo que no debería ni saltos de línea, además no me explico porque sí funcionaría con el primer arreglo y con el segundo falle.

Comment: Podría ser que tengas espacios o saltos de línea antes de `<?php` o después de `?>` o entre ambas `?>   <?php`